# restangular filter object to array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter, restangular

I have this big resource object that has lots of methods inside of it with more objects, etc. I'm also converting xml into json for this.

One in particular is a resourceType object that sometimes has more than one resourceTypes. When 2 or more are present, it's an Array. When it's 1 it's just an object and I can't loop through it consistantly in my view.

I made a filter that checks if it's just an object then casts it to an array if it's not already one i'm just having trouble how to put it in my service call. Right now I have it has:

```
getResources: function(resourceId){
    var self = this;

    return Restangular.one('resource/resourceState', resourceId).get().then(function(response){

        $filter('castToArray')(response.resources.resourceState.resourceTypes)
        self.resources = response;

        return self.resources;
    });
},
```

This doesn't work. I want to maintain the integrity of the entire resources object but I want the resourceTypes method/object to cast to an array if only 1 is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on this the fix was quite simple.

I just set the above to:

```
getResources: function(resourceId){
    var self = this;

    return Restangular.one('resource/resourceState', resourceId).get().then(function(response){

        self.resources = response;
        self.resources.resourceState.resourceTypes = $filter('castToArray')(response.resourceState.resourceTypes);

        return self.resources;
    });
},
```

I just needed to set the the self.resources method to the response method with the filter casted on it. Okay I'm done.